# Don't understand why sub class must explicitly call base class constructor which has parameters

Tags: java

It seems not making sense for sub class is forced to call constructor of base class expicitly. If user can create its own constructor and not limited to base class, it will be more flexible. Anyone can tell me why this behavior is forced in JAVA? What is the good point for this?

```
class A
{                                                                                                    
  public A(String s)
  { 
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("BASE parameter constructor");
   }   
}

class C extends A
{  
       public C(String s)   
       {
        super(s);// why here compiler force to call constructor of base class
        System.out.println("Sub parameter constructor");
        }
}
```

Comment: Because to construct C, the compiler has to construct a A and need to know how (because there's no default no-arg constructor)

Answer (score 5):

because base class does not have a no-arg constructor which is called by default from subclass.

If you just do like this

```
public C(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("Sub parameter constructor");
    }
```

Then a default call to super constructor will be placed there and it will become

```
public C(String s)
    {
    super();
    System.out.println("Sub parameter constructor");
    }
```

But compiler does not provide a no-arg constructor as you have already defined a parameterized constructor as it is provided only when no other constructors are provided for the class.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new class, you do not have to specify a constructor. Java implicitly creates one for you during compile. Such a constructor is called a default constructor.

If your class doesn't specify a constructor, and if you subclass that class, similarly, you would not have to explicitly provide a constructor.

However, when you start to have a constructor in your class, then Java doesn't create a default constructor for you. If your constructor takes in at least one input parameter, then it is necessary for your subclass to call your parent class's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

[8.8.9. Default Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is
>   implicitly declared.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the
>   default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default
>   constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no
>   arguments.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly
>   declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor
>   (§6.6) that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.**